# Rails / typeahead.js on huge database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js

I am using typeahead.js to fill in a belongs_to field on a Rails form. When you create a Post, you pick the associated Book. There are thousands of records. The app is crashing on that page if I let typeahead.js look at Book.all, but if I limit to a couple hundred with Book.featured, it seems to work. How can I give the typeahead access to all the data, though?

/api/books.json returns all the records, not sure if that's helpful?

Here is how I have it set up:

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    cb(strs);
  };
};

books = <%= Book.featured.to_json.html_safe %>
var bookFinder = function(books) {
    $('#post_book_id').val(null)
    // $('#post_book_name').val(null)
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        matches = [];
        $.each(books, function(i, book){
            if(book.title.indexOf(q) !== -1){
                matches.push(book)
            }
        })
        cb(matches)
    }
}
$('#post_book_name').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 2
},
{
  name: 'books',
    displayKey: 'title',
  source: bookFinder(books)
});
$('#post_book_name').on('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
    $('#post_book_id').val(suggestion.id)
});
```

Comment: Can you show what a featured method it's like?

Comment: scope :featured, -> {where(:featured => true )}